# How to setup Router link in Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am newbie to react i basically have two questions. I am embedding a template into `ReactJs`.

1. I am having problem with slider. My slider's text is showing on navigation bar and slider is also not working. It has inline styling.
2. I have five components in my project. I would like to apply routing on one of them.

### Original Slider

[image]

### My Slider

[image]

### Here are my code files

1. index.html file

```
<!-- Document Wrapper
============================================= -->
<div id="wrapper" class="clearfix">
</div><!-- #wrapper end -->



    <!-- Go To Top
============================================= -->
<!-- <div id="gotoTop" class="icon-angle-up"></div> -->

<script src="/scripts/app.js"></script>

<!-- External JavaScripts
============================================= -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/plugins.js"></script>

<!-- Footer Scripts
============================================= -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/functions.js"></script>
```

1. Header.js

   import React from 'react';
   import logo from './images/chatfit_logo.png'
   class Header extends React.Component {
       render() {

   ```
       return (

       <header id="header" className="transparent-header full-header" data-sticky-class="not-dark">

   <div id="header-wrap">

   <div className="container clearfix">

       <div id="primary-menu-trigger"><i className="icon-reorder"></i></div>

       <div id="logo">
           <a href="index.html" className="standard-logo" data-dark-logo="images/logo-dark.png"><img src={logo} alt="Chatfit logo" /></a>
           <a href="index.html" className="retina-logo" data-dark-logo="images/logo-dark@2x.png"><img src="images/logo@2x.png" alt="Canvas Logo" /></a>
       </div>

       <nav id="primary-menu" className="dark">

           <ul>
               <li className="current"><a href="index.html"><div>Home</div></a>
               </li>
               <li><a href="#"><div>Our Mission</div></a>
               </li>
               <li className="mega-menu"><a href="#"><div>Services</div></a>
               </li>
               <li className="mega-menu"><a href="#"><div>App Overview</div></a>
               </li>
               <li className="mega-menu"><a href="#"><div>Team</div></a>
               </li>
               <li><a href="shop.html"><div>Contact Us</div></a>
               </li>
           </ul>

           <div id="top-cart">
               <a href="#" id="top-cart-trigger"><i className="icon-shopping-cart"></i><span>5</span></a>
               <div className="top-cart-content">
                   <div className="top-cart-title">
                       <h4>Shopping Cart</h4>
                   </div>
                   <div className="top-cart-items">
                       <div className="top-cart-item clearfix">
                           <div className="top-cart-item-image">
                               <a href="#"><img src="images/shop/small/1.jpg" alt="Blue Round-Neck Tshirt" /></a>
                           </div>
                           <div className="top-cart-item-desc">
                               <a href="#">Blue Round-Neck Tshirt</a>
                               <span className="top-cart-item-price">$19.99</span>
                               <span className="top-cart-item-quantity">x 2</span>
                           </div>
                       </div>
                       <div className="top-cart-item clearfix">
                           <div className="top-cart-item-image">
                               <a href="#"><img src="images/shop/small/6.jpg" alt="Light Blue Denim Dress" /></a>
                           </div>
                           <div className="top-cart-item-desc">
                               <a href="#">Light Blue Denim Dress</a>
                               <span className="top-cart-item-price">$24.99</span>
                               <span className="top-cart-item-quantity">x 3</span>
                           </div>
                       </div>
                   </div>
                   <div className="top-cart-action clearfix">
                       <span className="fleft top-checkout-price">$114.95</span>
                       <button className="button button-3d button-small nomargin fright">View Cart</button>
                   </div>
               </div>
           </div>


           <div id="top-search">
               <a href="#" id="top-search-trigger"><i className="icon-search3"></i><i className="icon-line-cross"></i></a>
               <form action="search.html" method="get">
                   <input type="text" name="q" className="form-control" value="" placeholder="Type &amp; Hit Enter.." readOnly/>
               </form>
           </div>

       </nav>

   </div>

   </div>
   </header>

       );
   }
   ```

   }
   export default Header;
2. Slider.js

   import React from 'react'

   class Slider extends React.Component {
       render() {
           return(

   ```
               <div className="swiper-container swiper-parent">
                   <div className="swiper-wrapper">
                       <div className="swiper-slide dark" style={{backgroundImage: "url(images/slider/swiper/1.jpg)"}}>
                           <div className="container clearfix">
                               <div className="slider-caption slider-caption-center">
                                   <h2 data-caption-animate="fadeInUp">Welcome to Canvas</h2>
                                   <p data-caption-animate="fadeInUp" data-caption-delay="200">Create just what you need for your Perfect Website. Choose from a wide range of Elements &amp; simply put them on your own Canvas.</p>
                               </div>
                           </div>
                       </div>
                       <div className="swiper-slide dark">
                           <div className="container clearfix">
                               <div className="slider-caption slider-caption-center">
                                   <h2 data-caption-animate="fadeInUp">Beautifully Flexible</h2>
                                   <p data-caption-animate="fadeInUp" data-caption-delay="200">Looks beautiful &amp; ultra-sharp on Retina Screen Displays. Powerful Layout with Responsive functionality that can be adapted to any screen size.</p>
                               </div>
                           </div>
                           <div className="video-wrap">
                               <video id="slide-video" poster="images/videos/explore.jpg" preload="auto" loop autoPlay muted>
                                   <source src='images/videos/explore.webm' type='video/webm' />
                                   <source src='images/videos/explore.mp4' type='video/mp4' />
                               </video>
                               <div className="video-overlay" style={{backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.55)'}}></div>
                           </div>
                       </div>
                       <div className="swiper-slide" style={{backgroundImage: 'url(images/slider/swiper/3.jpg)' , backgroundPosition: 'center top'}}>
                           <div className="container clearfix">
                               <div className="slider-caption">
                                   <h2 data-caption-animate="fadeInUp">Great Performance</h2>
                                   <p data-caption-animate="fadeInUp" data-caption-delay="200">You'll be surprised to see the Final Results of your Creation &amp; would crave for more.</p>
                               </div>
                           </div>
                       </div>
                   </div>
                   <div id="slider-arrow-left"><i className="icon-angle-left"></i></div>
                   <div id="slider-arrow-right"><i className="icon-angle-right"></i></div>
               </div>

               <a href="#" data-scrollto="#content" data-offset="100" className="dark one-page-arrow"><i className="icon-angle-down infinite animated fadeInDown"></i></a>

           </div>
       </section>

       );
   }
   ```

   }

   export default Slider;
3. App.js

   import React from 'react';
   import {BrowserRouter} from 'react-router-dom';
   import Header from './Header'
   import Slider from './Slider';
   import Section from './Section';
   import Footer from './Footer'
   class IndecisionApp extends React.Component {
       render() {

   ```
       return (
           <BrowserRouter>
               <div className="wrapper"> 
                   <Header/>
                   <Slider />
                   <Section />
                   <Footer /> <!-- Register.js goes here but should show in another page
               </div>
           </BrowserRouter>
       );
   }
   ```

   }

   export default IndecisionApp;

`Navigationbar` and `footer` are same for `Register.js`. I want, when I click on Register link. It should redirect to `Register.js` also displaying header and footer What should I do.

### Edit

Now in my `App.js` I have something like this

```
<BrowserRouter>
    <div className="wrapper"> 
        <Header/>
        <Route path="/register" component={Register}></Route>
        <Slider />
        <Section /> 
        <Footer />
     </div>
</BrowserRouter>
```

When i click on the link I want to hide `Slider` and `Section`

Thanks

Comment: DO you have any error in console ?

Comment: yes i have some warning in console

Comment: Check those warnings if for the libraries then correct your libraries for the slider etc... and for routing let me give you a simple code, it may help you.

Comment: my friend has embedded same template with almost same code as mine for him the slider is working fine

Comment: It can also be the problem if your libraries order is different. Kindly confirm that first.

Comment: order is correct i tried to change the order nothing worked

Comment: It is actually the problem of jquery this is causing the issue, check template version and the one which is compiling your React.

Answer (score 0):

In here you can import the `Link` as you know.

```
    <ul>
        <li className="current"><Link to="/register"><div>Register</div></Link>
        </li>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

Here import the `Route` as you know

```
  For Example

 <BrowserRouter>
        <div className="wrapper"> 
            <Header/>
            <Slider />
            <Section />
            <Route path="/register" component="Your_register_component"></Route>
            <Footer /> <!-- Register.js goes here but should show in another page
        </div>
    </BrowserRouter>
```

Comment: i am getting this error `./src/App.js
Attempted import error: 'react-router' does not contain a default export (imported as 'Route').`

Comment: `import {BrowserRouter, Route} from 'react-router-dom';` have you tried this ?

Comment: and are you using yarn and npm both or only one ?

Comment: i am only using npm

Comment: stop your server and start it again, and also compile your assets.

Comment: like running npm run dev or npm start to compile your assets and start server..

Comment: what should i write in `<Route path="/register" component="Your_register_component"></Route>` Your_register_component

Comment: `Your_register_component ` it means you might have register component you want to redirect to, it will just actually Switch to your register page, that you have made Component of.\

Comment: Just like you have `<Header/>` component same as you might have `<Register/>` component, I mean this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203246/discussion-between-qasim-ali-and-akhtar-munir).

Answer (score 0):

Try this @QasimAli

```js
<BrowserRouter>
  <div className="wrapper"> 
      <Header/>
      <Route  exact path="/register" component={Register}></Route>
      <Slider />
      <Section /> 
      <Footer />
   </div>
</BrowserRouter>
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```